# Get AWS IoT shadow state from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot, aws-iot

I'm trying to get the a IoT shadow state from inside a Lamda function. This is what I have so far in my Lambda function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: process.env.endpoint
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const params = {
  thingName: 'MyThing',
};

iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
  else     console.log('ok', data);        
});
```

But it never logs the data. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) I think the issue is that your function completes before handler's body has a chance to run.

One way to rectify this is through the use of `Promise` as shown in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async). For example:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: process.env.endpoint
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      const params = {
        thingName: 'MyThing',
      };

      iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
           console.log(err, err.stack); 
           reject();
        }
        else {
           console.log(data);
           resolve();
        }        
      });
  })

  return promise;
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. This was really helpful. The way AWS documentation is all over the place I am sure some may have missed the documentation, notes related to using Promise for cases such as this, or a case where one is doing a lengthy table scan etc.